# Make two GitLab rules to an and instead of an or

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab CI job that should only run when both requirements are satisfied:

- The file `path/to/some/file` exists; and
- there are changes to any `*.txt` files in `path/to/some` recursively.

I used the following code:

```yaml
abc:
  stage: foo
  rules:
    - exists:
        - path/to/some/file
    - changes:
        - path/to/some/**/*.txt
  script:
    - echo "1"
```

However, the job gets created when `path/to/some/file` exists, but *no* file changes appear that match `path/to/some/**/*.txt`.

How can I make these two different rules to an and instead of an or?

Comment: [_"Rules are evaluated in order until the first match."_](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-rules)

Comment: Ok thanks, please make this an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

At most, one rule matches for a job. If you want to combine multiple conditions (`if:`, `changes:` and/or `exists:`) with a logical *AND*, put them in the same rule.

For example:

```yaml
build-dockerfile:
  rules:
    - if: $SOME_VARIABLE
      changes:  # if $SOME_VARIABLE is set AND changes occur to dockerfile
        - Dockerfile
```

Comment: But this is only true for variables, not for things like *exists* as far as I know

Comment: Hmm, that may be @fsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf -- The documentation doesn't provide any examples of combining `exists:` and `changes:`, but it does suggest that conditions in the same rule should be combined with a logical _AND_. I don't think I've ever used this exact combination before though. I will do some testing later today and let you know what I find out.

Comment: Okay, cool, happy to hear your feedback!